# Best SDK for implementing whatsapp-like videochat?

Tags: webrtc, videochat

What is the best way of implementing a whatsapp-like videochat and textchat into ones own app? Reliability, ease of integrating and documentation and lastly pricing.

- Agora: [link](https://dashboard.agora.io/signin)
- Twilio [link](https://www.twilio.com)
- Sinch [link](https://www.sinch.com)
- Opentok/Tokbox [link](https://opentokdemo.tokbox.com)

Comment: I came across Mirrorfly. Their Video chat SDK allows you to have high quality video calls with help of their inbuilt WebRTC integration.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I use https://connectycube.com

They have iOS(Swift), Android(Kotlin/Java) and web version(pure JS and Cordova for mobile browser). They use WebRTC to manage video calls, works fine for now.

Main features:

- 1-1 video chat
- Group video chat
- Cross-platform
- WebRTC based
- Screen sharing
- VP8/H264 video codecs supported
- Mute/Unmute audio/video stream
- Switch video input devices (cameras)
- Video recording

They have ready-to-go guides and code samples on GitHub for each platform:

- iOS video calling guide https://developers.connectycube.com/ios/videocalling
- Android video calling guide https://developers.connectycube.com/android/videocalling
- Javascript video calling guide https://developers.connectycube.com/js/videocalling

Comment: Looks like a good solution with a good documentation. Can encryption be added there?
Thanks

Comment: @StefanBadi yes, for example via https://otr.cypherpunks.ca/ or similar. You could get more info at https://connectycube.com/contact/

Comment: Thank you. That sounds like a very comprehensive solution to get started with chats

Comment: can it provide enterprise ?

Comment: Hi, could you share how many active users can use the FREE plan and is there any limitation on the duration of calls? I want to use it for P2P video calling.